# Unable to connect to Event hub through private end point from databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-eventhub

I have created a private end point on the event hub and trying to access that from databricks through the private end point.

The databricks and event hub private end point are in the same Vnet but different sub nets.
It's giving me this error 'No subject alternative DNS name matching' in databricks when trying to connect through private end point.

When I did nslookup on the private end point, it is giving the correct IP address.

I can connect to the event hub from databricks through public IP addresses but not through private end point.
Any idea?